# puppeteer executablePath Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for the WS endpoint URL to appear in stdout

Tags: puppeteer

I want to use the webdriver using the executable path, I get this error, yesterday I thought maybe it was with the driver I was installing others, I do not know what to do, I found nothing like this and decided to write here, very much need to use webdriver

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'
import { resolve } from 'path'

const main = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: resolve('chromedriver_mac_arm64', 'chromedriver')
    })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto('https://whoer.net', {
        waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
    })
    await sleep(40_000)

    await browser.close()
}

main()

function sleep(sec: number): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, sec))
}
```